# How are additional costs calculated with the `requestHeapFrame` instruction?

Tags: compute-budget, heap

When I use the `requestHeapFrame` instruction to request more heap, I expect it likely adds additional cost to my transaction. How do I calculate how much additional cost it would take?

Comment: Just want to point out that as of right now, September 2023, the requestHeapFrame ix doesn't seem to do anything. The heap still goes out-of-memory in the normal amount of space in applications where we have tested it on localnet/devnet, unless this has been updated in the last few weeks.

Answer (score 3):

The `requestHeapFrame` instruction adds an additional [8 compute units](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e088eb2be0c1111c438f1cf716d7fd8ae6ebcd9f/program-runtime/src/compute_budget.rs#L183) per 32K heap requested.

This means if you have a compute budget instruction for `requestHeapFrame` and use `SetComputeUnitPrice` to set the microLamport price to 1 microLamport, you would incur
`8 * (heapRequested / 32K) * computeUnitPrice` more in microLamports on your transaction.

If you're interested in requesting more heap for your program, you'll have to add [some code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/511182479b0e34d9393f1cfedb50a8ebcfcba834/programs/sbf/rust/custom_heap/src/lib.rs#L24) in order to make it possible to increase the total heap available.